# Subtraction Game with Two Piles of Stones

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

In this subtraction game, there are two piles of stones, and a player can take between 1 and 4 stones from the first pile or between 1 and 5 from the second. I am trying to determine which positions are in the set $P$. This is my attempt so far:

Denote $X$ as the number of stones in the first pile and $Y$ the number of stones in the second. Denote a position in the game as $(X, Y)$. $(0, 0) \in P$ is the terminal position (this is normal play).

Case 1: $X, Y \in P$. Then $X = 5k$ and $Y = 6l$ for $k, l \in \mathbb{N}$. So $(X, Y) \in P$.

Case 2: $X \in P$, $Y \in N$, or vice versa. Then $(X, Y) \in N$.

(I can prove these using induction, I'm just leaving that part out, because here is where I'm stuck):

Case 3: $X, Y \in N$. What I've done is draw out a grid of possible $(X, Y)$ positions and labeled them as $N$ or $P$. This is what my list looks like: $(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (6, 1), (7, 2), (8, 3), (9, 4), (1, 7), (2, 8), (3, 9), (4, 10), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8,9), (9, 10)$ are all in $P$. I'm trying to generalize this somehow and am struggling to proceed. Any assistance/comments would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the source of this problem? Is it for a class and/or textbook? If so, what results/examples about games have been recently covered. There is a shortcut to seeing what the pattern in your list is. But maybe this problem is intended as motivation for that shortcut (so that citing it would be cheating yourself/the problem's intent), and it's probably reasonable to figure out the pattern in case 3 without it.

Comment: Assuming you're supposed to see the pattern rather than using some more powerful techniques/results, I would say your list in case 3 looks correct, and you should think about the pattern in case 1 and the beginning of your case 3 list, and see if you can guess an idea that would work. Or for another perspective, the pair $(X,Y)$ is a $P$-position if it has the form in case 1 or is on your list in case 3. If you put those together, is there a general condition that seems to cover both cases?

Comment: @MarkS. For a class--we haven't yet gotten to the Sprague-Grundy Theorem, only Bouton's Theorem. So I think we're just supposed to figure out the pattern without any special tricks.

Comment: @MarkS. One thing I'm noticing is that you can simply take $(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)$ and add $5$ to $X$. Or, you can add $6$ to $Y$. Or, you can add $5$ to $X$ and $6$ to $Y$! So perhaps the pattern is: start with $(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)$ which are all in $P$. Now, any pair satisfying $(X + 5k, Y + 6l)$ for $k, l \geq 0$ and in $\mathbb{Z}$ is in $P$. How does this look?

Comment: You have the right idea/pattern, but your phrasing in "any pair satisfying..." is a little unclear. The $P$-positions have the form ____ (fill in the blank and prove it). At this point, I think you can do the work to try to prove things and post an answer to your own question here. Maybe wait until after the deadline so you don't spoil things for any of your classmates, though.